# git bash on windows confusing argument passing behavior start with '/'

Tags: git-bash

I use git bash on windows 10 and I'm a c# developer. I have made a .net 6 console, code like this:

```csharp
foreach(var arg in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arg);
}
```

If I use git-bash to call this console like `.\test /abc`
the result would be :

```bash
#protable git
C:/soft/git/abc
#or installer
C:/Program Files/Git/abc
```

If I use `.\test //abc`, the argument passing would be just fine like running on cmd or powershell. The result would be:

```bash
/abc
```

I can't understand why the git install path would be passing to the argument since my working dir is not there. Any one can provide some information?